# how to get newly added rows in db2 tables after adding column to it

Tags: database, db2

I have fews columns in db2 table and then I have added one more column to it. I then insert few rows in the table. How to get the newly added rows after table alteration? 
Note : There is no timestamp related column in table , so the logic based on it  cant be used.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Without a timestamp there is no "before" or "after" rows, they're all the same. Rows inserted before the change will all have null values in the newly added column, so you could use that fact to distinguish them from those you inserted after the change (if the new rows have non-null values in that column).

Comment: Thanks....I was looking for any property provided by DB2  which could let us know when the rows are added (might be timestamp maintained by db2)...I am not sure about it....